# How to generate a grouped stacked barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to generate a  grouped stacked barplot in ggplot2. My grouped variable is "person" . Here is my script :

```
v1
   person variable value cat
1       A   value1   100  a1
2       A   value1   150  a2
3       B   value1   120  a3
4       B   value1    80  a4
5       B   value1   150  a5
6       A   value2    25  a1
7       A   value2    30  a2
8       B   value2    45  a3
9       B   value2    30  a4
10      B   value2    30  a5

ggplot(v1, aes(x = cat, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
+   geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') + facet_grid(~ person)
```

[image: here is the resulted output]

Why do I have the extra samples  samples ID(cat) in my group? How can remove them ?

Thanks in advance!
DD

Comment: add `scales = "free_x"` in `facet_grid`

Comment: Thanks a lot, very useful!